# Send HTTP callbacks with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, message-queue, webhooks

I have Spring Boot app and I need to implement [WebHooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook). I'm newbie to messaging systems but I think I can use ActiveMQ to put in queue the messages and then send them as HTTP POST requests to specified URLs.

Is it correct solution? 
Is there any examples? Because I can't fund anything about it.